# How to include related tables in DbSet.Find()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

If I want to include related objects in an EF7 query, it's nice and easy:

```
var myThing = db.MyThings
                .Include(t => t.RelatedThing)
                .Where(t => t.SomeCondition == true)
                .ToList();
```

Also, there's a nice method on the `DbSet<T>` that makes it easy to load a single object by its key:

```
var myThing = db.MyThings.Find(thingId);
```

But now I want to load `myThing` by its Id, along with its `RelatedThing`.  Unfortunately (and understandably) `.Find()` is a method of `DbSet<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`.  Obviously I could do this:

```
var myThing = db.MyThings
                .Include(t => t.RelatedThing)
                .SingleOrDefault(t => t.MyThingId == thingId);
```

But I specifically want to use the `.Find()` method, because it's nice and generic and I'm writing a method that generically loads a record along with "included" relationships specified by an `Expression<Func<T, object>>`.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Please excuse me for the silly question, but I can't find `Find` method in EF Core, where it is located?

Comment: @IvanStoev it's a method on the `DbSet<T>` class, in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace.  Make sure you're working with the latest pre-release version.

Comment: I'm with RTM :)

Comment: Anyway, I doubt it can be used for eager loading - it wasn't possible in EF6. I guess you'll have to use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39372237/repository-generic-method-getbyid-using-eager-loading/39376142#39376142) adjusted for EF Core.

Comment: @IvanStoev, that's a good suggestion.  Please can you write it up as an answer?

Comment: @IvanStoev, that's funny to find you on a related question that has answer.

Comment: See also: [How to specify eager loading with DBContext Find method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39088847/861716).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was not possible with EF6, I don't think EF Core will change that. This is because the main purpose of the `Find` method is to bring the already loaded entity from the local cache, or load it from the database if it's not there. So the eager loading (`Include`) can be used only in the later case, while in the former it would need to perform explicit loading. Combining both in a single method might be technically possible, but is hard.

I think you should take the `FirstOrDefault` (or `SingleOrDefault`) route combined with eager loading. You can see a sample implementation for EF6 in [Repository generic method GetById using eager loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39372237/repository-generic-method-getbyid-using-eager-loading/39376142#39376142). It could be adjusted for EF Core like using the `dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties` to find the PK properties and build the predicate. Also since EF Core includes are bit more complicated (require `Include` / `ThenInclude` chains), you might find interesting this thread [Can a String based Include alternative be created in Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312437/can-a-string-based-include-alternative-be-created-in-entity-framework-core).

Answer (score 6):

Use Find, in combination with Load, for explicit loading of related entities.
Below a MSDN example:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
  var post = context.Posts.Find(2); 

  // Load the blog related to a given post 
  context.Entry(post).Reference(p => p.Blog).Load(); 

  // Load the blog related to a given post using a string  
  context.Entry(post).Reference("Blog").Load(); 

  var blog = context.Blogs.Find(1); 

  // Load the posts related to a given blog 
  context.Entry(blog).Collection(p => p.Posts).Load(); 

  // Load the posts related to a given blog  
  // using a string to specify the relationship 
  context.Entry(blog).Collection("Posts").Load(); 
}
```

here is [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#explicit)

Comment: If the table contains multiple relations then it will cause that many round trips to the database.